# CKEditor StrInsert: how to add a string with "\" backslash

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use StrInsert for CKEditor that allows you to create a custom dropdown added to the ckeditor toolbar, which simply outputs a text string to the editor.

> ```
> Each insertable string dict is defined by three possible keys:
>     'value': The value to insert.
>     'name': The name for the string to use in the dropdown.
>     'label': The voice label (also used as the tooltip title) for the string.
> Ex. strings.push(['value', 'name', 'label']);
> ```

My problem is that i want to output a string with a "\" backslash but I received an error.
This is the part of code that i use:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('strinsert',
{
    requires : ['richcombo'],
    init : function( editor )
    {
        //  array of strings to choose from that'll be inserted into the editor
        var strings = [];
        strings.push(['[WEB_LOG]', 'Extranet Login', 'Extranet Login']);
        strings.push(['[ALL_DIN=\\SRV-xxx\TimDoc$\Amm\con_(COD_ASS).pdf]', 'Note', 'Insert attachments pdf']);
```

In this code the output [WEB_LOG] it's ok but [ALL_DIN=\....] give me error I think because "\" is an escape character...
Is there a way to resolve?
Thank you

Comment: Have you try to write every '\' in escaping them like this '\\' ?

Comment: Yes I try but give me error again.

Comment: Can you try to replace your '\' with the html code '&#92' ?